# Resize iframe by mouse drag

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page that consists of two iframes where they divide the page into two parts.

**Is there a way to resize the division of the page using mouse drag?**

I would prefer a solution that *does not require* JQuery as we're not using it at the moment (We are using Microsoft AJAX library but I couldn't find a solution that leverages it).

Thanks.